How to avoid "ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package" error
Background:  I have a bunch of small-to-medium python programs that I'm trying to simplify by factoring out common code into a module that all the programs import.
The problem I run into is that when I put the common code into common.py in the same directory as all the programs, and do from . import common, I get the error

ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Which doesn't make a lot of sense.  From my (limited) understanding of python, a "module" is just a file with a .py extension and a "package" is just a directory containing modules.  All of my files are in one directory, so isn't that the "package"?  How is it even possible to have "no known parent package" -- by definition all the files are in a directory and that is a package.  Various places talk about an __init__.py file, so I've tried adding that to the directory, but that makes no difference.
So I guess my question is: what exactly is a python package, and when exactly is a directory NOT a package?  What does it mean to not have a parent package, and how does that occur?  I've looked at various introductory python documents like What is a python package as well as python documentation like Python packages (which mentions the __init__.py file), but I can't seem to find anything that really explains what is actaully going on under the hood, or how to understand what this error means and how to fix it.

Is this what you're looking for? Relative imports in Python 3. TLDR: it depends how you're running it (the module/script that imports common).

Or Relative imports for the billionth time

try this instead
from common import *

To repeat your result, in the 'test' folder, we have 4 files:



init.py     Empty file, telling python that this directory should be considered a Python package.




common.py



def func1():
    print("func1")

def func2():
    print("func2")




test1.py



from common import *
func1()

func2()


4 test2.py

import common
common.func1()
common.func2()

In the terminal, we could run either test1.py or test2.py. Both should work. In practice, you could have all your helper functions in one folder under your project folder as:
myproject/
    main.py
    utils/
        __init__.py
        func_module1.py
        func_module2.py

Then import like this:
import utils.func_module1 as mod1
mod1.func1()


Per PEP-8: “Wildcard imports (from <module> import *) should be avoided, as they make it unclear which names are present in the namespace, confusing both readers and many automated tools.”

Then, he needs import common, and then use methods of this 'commone' module you have to write common.method().

@s3dev Yeah, that's not even necessary. The equivalent of from . import common is just import common.

This gives me "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'common'"

Just edit the post, hopefully this will help. You will need init.py file to tell python that the current folder is a package
